When using entire population statistics, are p-values, confidence intervals, and standard errors still relevant?
I’m analyzing the full set of arbitration cases under UNCITRAL (the entire population, not just a sample) using OLS regression. Since I have data on every case, I’m wondering whether traditional metrics like p-values ($p$), confidence intervals ($CIs$), and standard errors ($SE$) still make sense. Are these metrics just for sample data, or do they still have a role when working with the full population? If not, what’s the best way to interpret the results in this case?
Also, does it matter if I have time-fixed effects in my model?
Note, I do not want to say anything about future cases but just what explains some historical outcomes.

In principle, those statistics exist to help us generalize from a sample to a broader population. If you're looking at the entire population, they aren't very meaningful. That said, I think that people are often interested in generalizing to a broader hypothetical population (e.g., what if we looked at even more arbitration cases, e.g., over the next ten years - would these patterns hold up)? In that case, they still make sense.
